# Replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, replace, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with about 20 columns.

It is possible to replace all occurrences of a string (here a newline) by manually writing all column names:

```
df['columnname1'] = df['columnname1'].str.replace("\n","<br>")
df['columnname2'] = df['columnname2'].str.replace("\n","<br>")
df['columnname3'] = df['columnname3'].str.replace("\n","<br>")
...
df['columnname20'] = df['columnname20'].str.replace("\n","<br>")
```

This unfortunately does not work:

```
df = df.replace("\n","<br>")
```

Is there any other, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use `replace` and pass the strings to find/replace as dictionary keys/items:

```
df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1\n', '2\n', '3'], 'b': ['4\n', '5', '6\n']})
>>> df
   a    b
0  1\n  4\n
1  2\n  5
2  3    6\n

>>> df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)
   a      b
0  1<br>  4<br>
1  2<br>  5
2  3      6<br>
```

Note that this method returns a new DataFrame instance by default (it does not modify the original), so you'll need to either reassign the output:

```
df = df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)
```

or specify `inplace=True`:

```
df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me! Pandas version '0.15.1', python 2.7.9, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  9 2015, 16:20:48)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1\n', '2\n', '3'], 'b': ['4\n', '5', '6\n']})
>>> df
     a    b
0  1\n  4\n
1  2\n    5
2    3  6\n
>>> df.replace({'\n': '<br>'})
     a    b
0  1\n  4\n
1  2\n    5
2    3  6\n
>>>
`

Comment: How come when I did `df.replace({'...': 'stuff'}, regex=True)`, it replaced not just '...', but ALL the strings? %\ ... left the numbers tho ...

Comment: @Raksha - in regex, '.' matches any character! (except line terminators.)

Comment: @NicholasMorley, oh yeah, I forgot x.x ... how would I replace a string that is  '...' then ?

Comment: Use backslash to match a character literally, and {n} to quantify. Thus: `df.replace('\.{3}', 'stuff', regex=True)`

Comment: This method does not work. What does work is Mykola Zotko method. 
`for col in df.columns:
   df[col] = df[col].str.replace('\n', '<br>')`

Comment: @ShaneS: it still works fine for me (Python 3.10, pandas 1.4.2). The only difference with the method you've highlighted is that `df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)` returns a new DataFrame object instead of updating the columns on the original DataFrame. So you'll need to reassign the output, e.g. `df = df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)`.

Answer (score 23):

It seems Pandas has change its API to avoid ambiguity when handling regex. Now you should use:

```
df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1\n', '2\n', '3'], 'b': ['4\n', '5', '6\n']})
>>> df
   a    b
0  1\n  4\n
1  2\n  5
2  3    6\n

>>> df.replace({'\n': '<br>'}, regex=True)
   a      b
0  1<br>  4<br>
1  2<br>  5
2  3      6<br>
```

Comment: You can also use the "inplace=True" to avoid creating a copy  -- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Doc says nothing about not creating a copy. Afaik there are only 2 functions that do not create a copy in pandas = inplace does not save anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over all columns and use the method `str.replace`:

```
for col in df.columns:
   df[col] = df[col].str.replace('\n', '<br>')
```

This method uses regex by default.

Answer (score -1):

This will remove all newlines and unecessary spaces. You can edit the **' '.join** to specify a replacement character

```
    df['columnname'] = [''.join(c.split()) for c in df['columnname'].astype(str)]
```