# Python : In DataFrame, How to replace float value to string value?

Tags: python, replace

In my situation, I want

input:

```
No col1 col2 col3  
1  -999 -999 -999  
2    1    2    3  
3    2    4  -999  
4    3    5  blank
```

output:

```
No col1 col2 col3    
1    .    .    .    
2    1    2    3    
3    2    4    .   
4    3    5    .
```

how to convert -999 --> '.' ?

Comment: Can you also post your effort and where are you failing..?

Comment: df =df.replace([-999, '  '], ['.','.'])                                                          ValueError: could not convert string to float: .

Comment: Have a look at(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do as follows:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
d = {'col1': [-999, 1,2,3], 'col2': [-999, 2,4,5],  'col3': [-999, 3,-999,-999]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df[df==-999] = '.'

print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    .    .    .
1    1    2    3
2    2    4    .
3    3    5    .
```

Not sure what `black` is in your question. I just made it into -999 in the example.

Comment: but your code in error :                                   ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '.'

Comment: Please provide more details for you question. Code for creation of your example dataframe would be good start. also what version of pandas you use and python.