# Replacing zero values in dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace some of the values in the foll. dataframe:

dataframe_a

```
Y2000   Y2001   Y2002    Y2003    Y2004    Item    Item Code
34        43      0      0          25     Test      Val
```

I would like to replace the values in the columns with a numeric value derived by multiplying a scalar (say 0.5) by all values in this dataframe:

dataframe_b

```
Y2000   Y2001   Y2002    Y2003    Y2004    Item    Item Code
34        43      10      20        25     Test      Val
```

So, in dataframe_a value for column Y2002 should be 10 * 0.5 and value for column Y2003 should be 20 * 0.5

Currently, I am doing this:

```
df = dataframe_a[dataframe_a == 0]
df = df * dataframe_b * 0.5
```

However, not sure how I can update dataframe_a with the new values

Comment: What about databrame.replace() : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: I saw replace, but not sure how to use it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the boolean mask and then call `fillna`:

```
In [58]:
fill = df2.select_dtypes(include = [np.number]) * 0.5
df1 = df1[df1!=0].fillna(fill)
df1

Out[58]:
   Y2000  Y2001  Y2002  Y2003  Y2004  Item Item  Code
0     34     43      5     10     25  Test        Val
```

Here `df1[df1 !=0]` will produce a df of the same shape with `NaN` values where the condition is not met, you can then call `fillna` on this and pass the other df which will replace the `NaN` values where the index and columns align.

The result of the boolean mask:

```
In [63]:
df1[df1!=0]

Out[63]:
   Y2000  Y2001  Y2002  Y2003  Y2004  Item Item  Code
0     34     43    NaN    NaN     25  Test        Val
```

Comment: That replaces the `NaN` values buy the ones from `df2` not by a scalar multiplier as he asked.

Comment: No idea, hope that'll help

Comment: thanks @EdChum, excellent explanation as usual. I didn't downvote :)

Answer (score 2):

A generic one, in case you don't know the location of the `0` value:

```
new_df = 0.5*df2[df==0]
new_df.fillna(df, inplace=True)
print(new_df)

    0   1  2  3   4     5    6
0  34  43  5  5  25  Test  Val
```

Where `dataframe_a` is `df` and `dataframe_b` is `df2`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
randn = np.random.randn
s = Series(randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
d = {'one' : Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
df.replace(1, 12*4)  # replace all values 1 by 12*4
df
```

Ref about `replace()` : [Replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
dataframe_a[dataframe_a == 0] = 0.5 * dataframe_b[dataframe_a == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas-dataframe-where) might be what you need.  You would have to construct another `dataframe` with the specific column values that you want to substitute.

I don't have Pandas installed here so I can't show a dataframe example - but it works similarly with numpy arrays.

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5])
>>> subst
array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70])
>>> k = -.5
>>> np.where(a == 0, subst * k, a)
array([  1.,   2., -15.,   3.,   4., -30.,   5.])
>>>
```

---

One difference with the `dataframe` is that it can do an in-place substitution and you only have to specify the *other* `dataframe` (the one with the substitute values).

Finally a Pandas example:

```
>>> 
>>> df
   d  e  f
a  0  1  1
b  1  1  0
c  1  0  1
>>> s
    d   e   f
a  10  20  30
b  10  20  30
c  10  20  30
>>> k = -.5
>>> df.where(df != 0, other = s * k)
   d   e   f
a -5   1   1
b  1   1 -15
c  1 -10   1
>>> 
>>> df.where(df != 0, other = s * k, inplace = True)
>>> df
   d   e   f
a -5   1   1
b  1   1 -15
c  1 -10   1
>>>
```

[Some examples from the pydata site.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking)