# How to extract content from the regex output which has square bracket in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a Python's (2.7) Pandas DF which has columns which looks something like this :

```
       email
['jsaw@yahoo.com']
['jfsjhj@yahoo.com']
['jwrk@yahoo.com']
['rankw@yahoo.com']
```

I want to extract email from it without the square bracket and single quotes. Output should like this :

```
     email
jsaw@yahoo.com
jfsjhj@yahoo.com
jwrk@yahoo.com
rankw@yahoo.com
```

I have tried the suggestions from this answer :[Replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python) . But its not working. Any help will be appreciated.

edit:
What if I have array of more than 1 dimension. something like :

```
          email
  ['jsaw@yahoo.com']
  ['jfsjhj@yahoo.com']
  ['jwrk@yahoo.com']
  ['rankw@yahoo.com','fsffsnl@gmail.com']
  ['mklcu@yahoo.com','riserk@gmail.com', 'funkdl@yahoo.com']
```

is it possible to get the output in three different columns without square brackets and single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) if `type` of values is `string`:

```
print type(df.at[0,'email'])
<type 'str'>

df['email'] = df.email.str.strip("[]'")
print df
              email
0    jsaw@yahoo.com
1  jfsjhj@yahoo.com
2    jwrk@yahoo.com
3   rankw@yahoo.com
```

If `type` is `list` [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `Series`:

```
print type(df.at[0,'email'])
<type 'list'>

df['email'] = df.email.apply(pd.Series)
print df
              email
0    jsaw@yahoo.com
1  jfsjhj@yahoo.com
2    jwrk@yahoo.com
3   rankw@yahoo.com
```

EDIT: If you have multiple values in array, you can use:

```
df1 = df['email'].apply(pd.Series).fillna('')
print df1
                  0                  1                 2
0    jsaw@yahoo.com                                     
1  jfsjhj@yahoo.com                                     
2    jwrk@yahoo.com                                     
3   rankw@yahoo.com  fsffsnl@gmail.com                  
4   mklcu@yahoo.com   riserk@gmail.com  funkdl@yahoo.com
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response.. Type of my column is <type 'numpy.ndarray'> . I tried to convert it into list and then apply the series method but its giving a error "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,6) into shape (6)".. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One question - How many columns have your dataframe with real data?

Comment: I have total 17 columns but only three are of array type.. the email column which is an array can have 1-D, 2-D or any dimensional array.. the column  looks like :                                                                                        email
['jsaw@yahoo.com']
['jfsjhj@yahoo.com']
['jwrk@yahoo.com']
['rankw@yahoo.com']
['njdfh@yahoo.com','njdfh@gmail.com'] . So I also have multiple emails in the same column.

Comment: Can you update your question and add your desired output? If there are multiple emails, output is multiple columns?

Comment: yes sure.. I currently have 11 reps .. 4 more to go and then I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Btw, accepted answer means clicking to empty tick under 0. Then color is changed to green and you get 2 points. If you need change column names use `df1.columns = ['a','b','c']` and if need join more dataframes together by columns use `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
from re import findall
s = "['rankw@yahoo.com']"                     
m = findall(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9@'._]+)\]", s) 
print(m[0].replace("'",''))
```