# Change column values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas and trying to replace a value with another value. What am I doing wrong?

```
Source

Drive-By
Referral
Website
Radio
```

My snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

second = pd.read_csv('T:/pythonfiles/result2.csv')
second['Source'] = second['Source'].replace('Drive-By', 'Drive-by')
```

Error:

```
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13161)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13115)
KeyError: 'Source'
```

Comment: `KeyError: 'Source'`  means that Source is not a valid header name within your data file. Are you sure you have the column names correct?

Comment: Could you post an output of `print(second.columns.tolist())` after you read the CSV file (`read_csv()`...) - this will help toi understand what is wrong with your columns

Comment: Thanks @ Charles Morris. There is a semicolon in front of Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use the following as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python):

```
second.replace({'Drive-By': 'Drive-by'}, regex=True)
```

This would normally replace the value in all columns, but if you don't have 'Drive-By' recurring in other columns, this should work ok.

However, your error message suggests that you have issues with 'Source' not being recognized as a key in the table.