# replace single quote to double quote python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I want to replace single quote(') to double quote(") to make it proper json column value in python dataframe.

e.g. csv file looks like...

```
Unit Id Batch Id                               Items prod
A108    qa120  {'A': 123, 'B': 342, 'C': 454}   
P258    re015  {'A': 124, 'B': 234, 'C': 343}
```

I'm reading these values from csv to pandas dataframe. I tried several ways, but no luck.

```
df.replace("'",'"',inplace=True)
df.['<column_name>'].str.replace(r"[\',]",'"')
df = df['<column_name>'].str.replace(r"[\',]",'"')
```

Thanks for your help  in advance.

Comment: Input data is json? If yes, is possible create data sample?

Comment: Yes, Input data is json.
Here is sample data, I added this in my original question too.
Unit Id Batch Id Items prod 
A108 qa120 {'A': 123, 'B': 342, 'C': 454}
P258 re015 {'A': 124, 'B': 234, 'C': 343}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python)

Comment: @RuchitaP - But I think json file, not json dataframe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the problem is converting the single quote to double quotes *without* the restraint of doing it after you read it into a dataframe - you could change the `.csv` file *before* you read it into a dataframe:

`$ sed -i "s/'/\"/g" file_name.csv`

If you have to replace them *after* you read them into a dataframe, try the solution mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698756/5070837):

`df.replace({'\'': '"'}, regex=True)`

Comment: Thank you so much, this works as expected.
only minor change would be,  need to assign this back to df.
e.g. df = df.replace({'\'': '"'}, regex=True)

Comment: if dataframe is going to be same then we can add another option inplace as True to avoid  one line of code.... df = df.replace({'\'': '"'}, regex=True, inplace=True)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

If you want to update a column on a DataFrame, such as this

[image: Example of DataFram]

And let's say that you want to remove the double quotes from the first column.

Just do the following

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace(r"[\"]", r"'")
```

Here is the final result

[image: Output after running the code above]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert values to dictionaries like:

```
import ast

df['<column_name>'] = df['<column_name>'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

But if input data are `json` file (string), better is use 
[`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import ast


df = pd.DataFrame({"Unit Id": ["A108", "P258"], "Batch Id": ["qa120", "re015"], "Items prod": ["{'A': 123, 'B': 342, 'C': 454}", "{'A': 124, 'B': 234, 'C': 343}"]})
df["NEW"] = df["Items prod"].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(json.dumps)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Batch Id                      Items prod Unit Id  \
0    qa120  {'A': 123, 'B': 342, 'C': 454}    A108   
1    re015  {'A': 124, 'B': 234, 'C': 343}    P258   

                              NEW  
0  {"A": 123, "C": 454, "B": 342}  
1  {"A": 124, "C": 343, "B": 234}
```