# How to replace a value universally across the entire data frame in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a dataset which has many variables: var1 .... varx; it is a concatenated dataset based on different survey versions (1st version, 2nd version, etc.)
Some of the variables have a value as "not in this version", because some of the measures were not captured in a previous survey version. 
How can I universally change any response of "not in this version" to "" (blank) in python pandas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.replace`

See, [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["hello", "hi", "not in this version"],'B': ["how", "not in this version", "are"]})
df.replace("not in this version", "")
```

Snippet

```
>>> df
                     A                    B
0                hello                  how
1                   hi  not in this version
2  not in this version                  are

>>> df.replace("not in this version", "")

       A    B
0  hello  how
1     hi     
2         are
```