# how to replace a string with different string in the column of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `Adult` and a column in the data frame `workclass` with thousands of rows. The column contains different string objects. I would like to replace all string `?` with string `Private` I have tried different variations of the code:

```
Adult.loc[:,'workclass'] = Adult.loc[:,'workclass'].replace(to_replace="?", value=str("Private"))
```

After running the code I do not get an error but when I run the code `Adult.workclass.unique()` the `?`is still in the data frame. How would I go about replacing the string with the correct string?
Thanks in advance

Comment: do u mind sharing a sample of ur dataset, with expected output? also is the '?' part of a string, or independent

Comment: Did you refer this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698756/10077354

Comment: I tried the link, however that seemed to work for all variables of that type in the data frame and I need to replace '?' with another string in one column and a different string in a separate column. Thank you for sharing the link though. And yes the '?' is part of a string. The expected output would be to replace any string '?' with the string 'Private" for the 'workclass' column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:
`Adult['workclass'] = Adult['workclass'].str.replace('?', 'Private')`

Comment: This is what I needed, Thank you!