# Pandas: Search and replace a string across all columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, contains

I'm trying to search for a string 'NONE' that is in uppercase across all columns in a dataframe and replace it with 'None'. If it is already 'None' I don't do anything.

I tried using the lambda function but its not working.

ps: In the data `None` is not a keyword. It is a string eg: "None"

```
df=data.apply(lambda row: 'None' if row.astype(str).str.contains('NONE').any() else row, axis=1)
```

**Sample input**

```
A    |    B
None |   234
NONE |   NONE
565  |   347
```

**Expected Output**

```
A    |    B
None |   234
None |   None
565  |   347
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace all occurrences of a string in a pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698710/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['None', 'NONE', '565'], 
                   'B': ['234', 'NONE', '347']})
# replace NONE by None
df = df.replace('NONE', 'None')
print(df)
```

```
      A     B
0  None   234
1  None  None
2   565   347
```